# How to mock a vendor package?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

```php
use Mockery;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use App\Services\S3Service;

class S3ServiceTest extends TestCase
{
    private $service;
    private $client;

    protected function setUp() : void
    {
        $this->client = Mockery::mock('overload:'.S3Client::class);
        $this->service = new S3Service();
    }

    /** @test */
    public function can_generate_pre_signed_url()
    {
        $this->client->shouldReceive('getCommand')->once();

        $this->service->generatePreSinedUrl('putObject', [
            'Bucket' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.bucket'),
            'Key' => 'testKey',
        ]);
    }
}
```

I am trying to test my class `S3Service` integration with `S3Client`

```php
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

class AwsS3Service
{
    private $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new S3Client([
            'version' => '2006-03-01',
            'region' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.region'),
            'signature_version' => 'v4',
            'credentials'=> [
                'key' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.key'),
                'secret' => config('filesystems.disks.s3.secret'),
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function generatePreSinedUrl(string $action, array $options, $expireAfter = '+5 minutes')
    {
        $command = $this->client->getCommand($action, $options);

        return $this->client->createPresignedRequest($command, $expireAfter);
    }
}
```

but I am getting this error: 
`Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Method Aws\S3\S3Client::getCommand() does not exist on this mock object`, I assume it has to do with `overload` keyword I am using but I don't know for sure.

How can to test `AwsS3Service` with  `Aws\S3\S3Client`  as a vendor package?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, but I'm getting errors because the mock is not being applied to S3Client class. Can you post the `S3Service` class referenced in your test?